# Bluetooth services on Google glass

Tags: bluetooth, google-glass, android-bluetooth

Has anyone tried SPP service (RFCOMM) on Google glass? I couldn't find any documentation anywhere listing what kind of Bluetooth protocol or profile that Google glass supports.

I have run an OBEX service search on the glass, and it seemed like Google glass doesn't support OBEX. Other than OBEX, what other BT profile is known to work properly on the glass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for SPP service (RFCOMM) you can use the UUID "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" as you might already know, I'm using this and it works fine at 115.2K of baudrate.

Then in a separate thread you manage the connection, if you go to the [developers portal](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) of Android they have an explained example and good info of the protocol.

Using the Bluetooth APIs, an Android application can perform the following:
-Scan for other Bluetooth devices
-Query the local Bluetooth adapter for paired Bluetooth devices
-Establish RFCOMM channels
-Connect to other devices through service discovery
-Transfer data to and from other devices
-Manage multiple connections

Hope this helps!

Comment: How did set the bluetooth on the glass to be discoverable? I've tried the android BT intent but Glass doesn't support it

Comment: I haven't been able to make it discoverable either, the connection works when you search the device from the glasses and start the connection from the glasses.